# Restcomm USSD - do not return a dialog

Tags: sip, gateway, ussd, restcomm

I have a working USSD gateway, messages between the user's device and the app are set.

But there is a particular type of message where I don't want to send any dialog back to the user. When a user puts a sim inside a phone for the first time, an automated USSD call is made - I receive it and handle it, to send a configuration SMS or such.

The thing is, then I don't want to send anything to the user - there is no need for the user to be aware of that call. I didn't succeed to do that up to now. Using type `End`, `Unidirectional` or `Abort` didn't change anything. The message `processUnstructuredSSRequest_Response` still has a `string` that will show on screen, needing the user to click the "OK" button.

How can I make this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. It's the `prearrangedEnd` dialog attribute, look for it in the doc https://www.restcomm.com/docs/core/ussd/USSD_Gateway_Admin_Guide.html#_attributes